# Laravel 5.2 redirect to slow

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. In project I am facing one problem when user acces non accessable page that time I checked user have access or not. If user have don't access particular page so I redirect to forbidden route. My code is working fine and redirect to forbidden route but when call forbidden route that time on same page wait for 2 to 3 seconds after that redirect to forbidden. I don't know what happen. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a middleware ? 
If you don't I would highly recommand you to check this out.
Also we can't do much without any piece of code.

Comment: please, information or request improvments should be posted as comments

Comment: I know but in order to post a comment the requirement is 50 reputation. So until I reach that I'm still trying to help people

Answer (score 0):

Hey to make fast your Laravel application try this

```
php artisan  view:clear
php artisan route:cache
```